# Synchronous execution of setimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I want the below function to be executed synchronously. Initially the 1st set time out should wait for 10 sec and call the function name which waits for 2 sec and returns back. I tried the below.

```
var ty = [1000, 1500, 200]
for (var i = 0; i < ty.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i)
    }, ty[i]);        
    name(i);
}

function name(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('the page name is' + i);
    }, 2000)
}
```

Comment: You cannot. There is no synchronous waiting in js.

Comment: the simple way is to increment the waiting time of the first call, this will do the same effect:

var ty = [1000, 1500, 200]
var delay =0;
for (var i = 0; i < ty.length; i++) {
    delay+= ty[i];
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i)
    }, delay);
        
    name(i);
}

function name(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('the page name is' + i);
    }, 200)
}

Comment: Btw, it's *milli*seconds not centiseconds. For 2s, you need to pass `2000`